# Image width & height reversed in visual Studio vb.net

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, image-size

When I view a photograph taken with a digital camera the height is 4000 and the width is 6016, if I take the picture by turning the camera 90 Deg. the height is 6016 and the width is 4000.  All is good, if I examine the properties of the image with file explorer(Windows 10) it looks correct for either picture.  If I view the picture in Photoshop or picture viewer all looks correct as far as orientation.  In my app I use exif to get the width and height it always shows width as 6016 and height as 4000.  if I get an image via code:

```
dim orgimage as bitmap = new bitmap("C:/image/picture.jpg")
```

the width is always 6016 and the height is always 4000, if I change the 4000 to 3999 via Photoshop the image width and height are correct in my app.  Is this a limitation of Visual Studios Visual Basic?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason for the difference is that the other applications are manually applying the correction for Exif.Image.Orientation (tag 274).

Just inspect this tag and rotate the bitmap accordingly.

```
Public Function OrientateImage(img As Image) As Boolean
    Const EXIF_ORIENTATION = 274
    Dim orientationTag = img.PropertyItems.FirstOrDefault(Function(x) x.Id = EXIF_ORIENTATION)
    If orientationTag IsNot Nothing Then
        Dim orientation As Short = BitConverter.ToInt16(orientationTag.Value, 0)
        Select Case orientation
            Case 3
                img.RotateFlip(RotateFlipType.Rotate180FlipNone)
            Case 6
                img.RotateFlip(RotateFlipType.Rotate90FlipNone)
            Case 8
                img.RotateFlip(RotateFlipType.Rotate270FlipNone)
            Case Else
                Return False
        End Select
    End If
    Return True
End Function
```

Comment: Nice function, Not checking orientation was my issue, function works perfect.

Comment: No problem. If this resolved your issue then please tick the answer as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

If you check the orientation property it might help answering/helping your issue with width and height being same when reading photo from Camera output. 
Please let us know your findings.

```
Dim orgimage As bitmap = New Bitmap("C:/image/picture.jpg", True) 
Dim otherImage As bitmap = New Bitmap("C:/image/picture2.jpg", True) 
'Orientation
Dim exifprop As Integer = orgimage.GetPropertyItem(274).Value(0)
Dim exifprop2 As Integer = otherImage.GetPropertyItem(274).Value(0)


'1 = Horizontal (normal)
'2 = Mirror horizontal
'3 = Rotate 180
'4 = Mirror vertical
'5 = Mirror horizontal and rotate 270 CW
'6 = Rotate 90 CW
'7 = Mirror horizontal and rotate 90 CW
'8 = Rotate 270 CW
```

[EXIF tags](http://www.sno.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool/TagNames/EXIF.html),
[PropertyItem.Id 274](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.imaging.propertyitem.id(v=vs.110).aspx)